# karaf-assembly 4.0.5 - zip ard tar.gz files are not generated at the end of a successful maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-karaf, karaf

I am an inexperienced Java and Maven developer, although I have got karaf-assembly builds to work a couple of years ago using the Karaf 3.0.1 release.

When attempting to generating a karaf-assemby 4.0.5 for a customised product build, the **zip** and **tar.gz** files are not created at the end of the maven build.  The **../target/assembly** directory is created each time the maven build is run and the completion status is always **"BUILD SUCCESS"**.

I suspect this this is because the POM file has an error highlighted by the Eclipse IDE at the  section for the **karaf-maven-plugin** directly on the  line, which is as follows:

**Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.5:assembly (execution: default-assembly, phase: process-
 resources)**

I can resolve this error in the IDE on the  line by removing the **"extensions"** line, but then I get a **"Project build error: Unknown packaging: karaf-assembly"** error on the **"packaging"** line.

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            **<!--  <extensions>true</extensions>  -->**
            <configuration>

                <startupFeatures></startupFeatures>
                <bootFeatures>
                  <feature>standard</feature>
                  <feature>management</feature>
                  <feature>jms</feature>

                </bootFeatures>
                <installedFeatures>
                </installedFeatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The POM file I am using is as follows:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>my.custom</groupId>
<artifactId>my.distribution</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>karaf-assembly</packaging>

<!-- PIP Operations Aspect Assembly properties -->
<properties>
    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <assembly.directory>${project.build.directory}/assembly/karaf-4.0.5</assembly.directory>
    <karaf.name>karaf</karaf.name>
    <karaf.version>4.0.5</karaf.version>
    <pip.name>Operations Aspect</pip.name>
</properties>

<dependencies>

     <dependency> 
         <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId> 
         <artifactId>framework</artifactId> 
         <version>4.0.5</version> 
         <type>kar</type> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency> 
         <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId> 
         <artifactId>framework</artifactId> 
         <version>4.0.5</version> 
         <classifier>features</classifier> 
         <type>xml</type> 
         <scope>runtime</scope> 
     </dependency> 
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <version>4.0.5</version>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope> 
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
         <artifactId>enterprise</artifactId>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
         <version>4.0.5</version>
         <type>xml</type>
         <scope>runtime</scope> 
     </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>    
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>  
        </plugins> 
    </pluginManagement>  


    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>

                <startupFeatures></startupFeatures>
                <bootFeatures>
                  <feature>standard</feature>
                  <feature>management</feature>
                  <feature>jms</feature>

                </bootFeatures>
                <installedFeatures>
                </installedFeatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing the execution settings:

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>assembly</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>package</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>archive</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Christian,  Many thanks for the information, but unfortunately it didn't work :-(   I now have the "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-maven-plugin:4.0.5:assembly (execution: default, phase: compile)" error in the IDE on the first "execution" line as well as the "plugin".   I think its this error that is preventing the the "karaf-maven-plugin" from executing at all.  Damo

Comment: The error comes from m2e and means that the plugin is not supported in the eclipse incremental builds. You should use Quick Fix on the error and set exclude in eclipse preferences. Btw. This does not affect the build on the command line at all.

Comment: Christian, Sorry that does work if I select "package" as the Maven goal during the build - my inexperience showing here I'm afraid.  I still have those Eclipse IDE errors, but I can build the assembly now!  Cheers Damo

Comment: Comments crossed - I will try the Quick Fix to get rid of the IDE errors.  :-)

Comment: Good to hear that. It would be nice if you could accept and upvote the answer if it helps you.